# Modifiers of attributes do not affect database in items.xml, why is that?

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud, items

In a Hybris project I have created **new** "custom" **entities** in **items.xml** (extending from GenericItem). 
After **ant clean all** and **ant initialize,** all the tables are generated perfectly, but the **optional** and **unique modifiers** don't have any effect on the specified attributes.
A snippet of my items.xml:

```
<attribute qualifier="someQualifier" type="java.lang.Long">
  <description>some desctiontion</description>
  <persistence type="property"/>
  <modifiers optional="false" unique="true"/>
</attribute>
```

In my database (tested on MySQL and HSQL) the optional and unique labeled attributes still have the default values (nullable = true, unique = false).
What could be the problem here?

Comment: Hybris seems to be a SAP related company. Maybe you mean Hibernate or another ORM.

Comment: I mean Hybris as the SAP related framework.

Comment: Ok. My mistake.

Comment: Have you checked in HMC whether your attribute is having optional flag false and unique flag true. Check in System -> Type -> Your_Model.

Answer (score 4):

These modifiers are for corresponding ValidateInterceptor not for table structure.
To specify column definition use:

```
    <persistence type="property">
        <columntype database="mysql">
            <value>int(11) not null</value>
        </columntype>
        ....
    </persistence>
```

To make it unique add indexes definition to your itemtype

```
    <indexes>
        <index name="someQualifierIDX" unique="true">
            <key attribute="someQualifier"/>
        </index>
    <indexes>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any possible solution to effect the table structure from the items.xml (or from any other place) through initialize to make the specified attributes to be unique or not null?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in here is jaloclass. After `ant all` it tries to create a jaloclass for your itemtype in the -items.xml file. If there is not a jaloclass for your itemtype, it creates with your modifiers.

On the other hand, if you try to modify (or delete) your itemtype in the -items.xml file, it means there is an existing jaloclass for your itemtype. It cannot modify the modifiers. To update modifiers, you should delete the jaloclass before `ant all`.